# Voice over speak tab bar below popup

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

I have a modal(popup) in that when voice over reads the last element after that it start speaking  tab bar elements.

I have used some property like:

```
view.accessibilityViewIsModal = true
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: self)
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: self)
self.isAccessibilityElement = true
view.isAccessibilityElement = true
```

Expected : it should not read tab bar below popup

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your views hierarchy may be the cause of your problem because the 'accessibilityViewIsModal' impacts only the view siblings. Take a look at the examples⟹ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#modal-view . 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can assign higher window to your view with some delay.

```
perform(#selector(self.assignWindowLevel), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.2)

 @objc func assignWindowLevel() {
    self.window?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1.2
}
```